# How to display elements of array inside an object

Tags: json, reactjs

I am having a JSON data file from I have to extract some information and display it using react js. I am getting stuck in display the elements of the array.

This is my data.js file

```
const details = [
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "057346956084",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.0.0.0/24"
      }
    ],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-novus-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "749444856751",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "172.31.0.0/16",
        region_three: "172.30.0.0/16"
      }
    ],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-gcs-normalization-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "238963201434",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.37.128.0/20",
        region_three: "10.37.144.0/20"
      }
    ],
    bu: "dcis",
    account_alias: "tr-tax-cp-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "209911870440",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.150.8.0/21",
        region_three: "10.168.0.0/21"
      }
    ],
    bu: "tax",
    account_alias: "tr-learning-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "933497097166",
    regions: [
      {
        region_six: "10.39.176.0/22",
        region_one: "10.39.160.0/21",
        region_three: "10.39.168.0/21",
        region_four: "10.39.124.0/22"
      }
    ],
    bu: "Corporates",
    account_alias: "tr-integrationpoint-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "777737700635",
    regions: [
      {
        region_nine: "10.152.158.0/24",
        region_ten: "10.97.207.0/24",
        region_one: "10.97.203.0/24",
        region_five: "10.97.205.0/24",
        region_four: "10.97.206.0/24",
        region_three: "10.97.204.0/24"
      }
    ],
    bu: "dcis",
    account_alias: "tr-isrm-ad-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "nonprod",
    account_number: "586447969888",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.226.208.0/21",
        region_three: "10.39.8.0/21"
      }
    ],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-content-console-preprod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },  {
    environment: "nonprod",
    account_number: "755189330144",
    regions: [{}],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-quicksight-preprod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "460300312212",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.152.140.0/22",
        region_four: "10.152.136.0/22"
      }
    ],
    bu: "dcis",
    account_alias: "tr-enterprise-cicd-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "470717676343",
    regions: [{}],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-wellarchitected-tool-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "prod",
    account_number: "249922119495",
    regions: [
      {
        region_one: "10.97.248.0/21",
        region_three: "10.62.56.0/21"
      }
    ],
    bu: "CIO and Central Tech",
    account_alias: "tr-authorities-prod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
  {
    environment: "nonprod",
    account_number: "043533679309",
    regions: [
      {
        region_five: "10.60.168.0/22",
        region_four: "10.60.164.0/22",
        region_ten: "10.37.212.0/23",
        region_one: "10.37.224.0/20",
        region_seven: "10.60.160.0/24",
        region_two: "10.37.214.0/23",
        region_three: "10.60.144.0/20"
      }
    ],
    bu: "corporate",
    account_alias: "tr-tax-proflgcy1-nonprod",
    resource_name: "account_info"
  },
]
```

This is my code where I have to display the data in the table.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./../css/index.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import details from '../data';

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { //state is by default an object
      accounts : details
   }
  }
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.accounts.map((account, index) => {
       const { environment, account_number,regions,bu,account_alias,resource_name } = account; //destructuring
       return (
          <tr key={index}>
             <td className="fixed-side">{account_number}</td>
             <td>{account_alias}</td>
             <td>{bu}</td>
             <td>{account_alias}</td>
             <td>{environment}</td>
              <td>{regions}</td>
          </tr>
       )
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll" className="table-scroll">
          <div className="table-fixed-right table-wrap">
            <table className="main-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="fixed-side" scope="col">Account Number</th>
                  <th scope="col">Account Alias</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-east-2</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-east-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-gov-west-1</th>
                  <th scope="col">us-gov-east-1</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

when I am trying to map through the data and destructure the elements when I am trying to display the element I am getting error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {region_one}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

Could anyone please help me

Comment: What do you expect to see in the table cell that has the `regions` value?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because each element of details contains a nested object array by the name of regions. What you can do is remove the "{" and "}" inside the regions array and then refer to it as a simple array while rendering

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a javascript Array/Object or anything really inside HTML(without the  tags). You can do what Willy Wonka above has said. Just put the values of the object inside the array as

```
['172.31.0.0/16','172.30.0.0/16']
```

or just have an object as value of regions as

```
  {
    region_one: "172.31.0.0/16",
    region_three: "172.30.0.0/16"
  }
```

You can iterate through the regions in the object as

```
let regionString = ''
for(let region in regions){
    regionString+ = region + ' ' 
}
```

Then you can have a string where you will put the string in the data cell as {regionString} sth like that. Hope you got it :)

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more